# Как быстро запустить приложение в Android Studio?

Tags: android

Android studio использует такую же систему как в Jrebel для быстрого запуска точнее обновления приложения.

Есть ли какая - нить другая система для быстрого обновления приложения. К примеру изменил я 1 класс. Раз и приложение обновилось.

И не надо заново лазить по 10 окнам чтобы добраться до 11. Jrebel не обновляет приложение. допустим я нахожусь на 11 окне. Нажимаю update Jrebel и результат не меняется

Comment: В Android Studio есть [функция InstantRun](https://habrahabr.ru/company/livetyping/blog/304640/), это она *"такая же система"*?. Ваш вопрос в том, как использовать Jrebel в Android Studio?

Comment: Скорее всего в JRebel вы нажимаете не на ту кнопку. Перезапуск вместо обновления.

Comment: Jrebel работает с API 11. А InstantRun работает с API 21 вроде.

Суть у них одинаковая. Но проблема в том что допустим в 11 окне я изменил цвет кнопки. Нажиаю Apply тобишь update. 7 сек и приложение обновилось. Но цвет не изменился. Чтобы увидеть результат надо выйти из приложения и заново зайти. По сути InstantRun и Jrebel ничего не делают

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Жмите [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и приложение будет обновляться, а не запускаться сначала. Но это зачастую когда внесены изменения во `view` элементы, все зависит от глубины изменений, иногда все же требуется полный перезапуск сделать.

Comment: На самом деле [в документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#instant-run) однозначно указано, когда происходит обновление, когда перезапуск. Вообще различается три режима: холодный, теплый и горячий рестарт и когда какой будет запущен четко определено, без всяких неопределенностей, как "зачастую" и  "глубина изменений"